# Crontab not piping to file (LINUX)

Tags: linux, pipe, cron

The cronjob does not pipe the output from another script to a file but it works I execute it (not same user, chmod for both files is set to 777).

```
#! /bin/sh

. /disk2/etc/env_cron
SUBJ="Test"
TEXT=/disk2/home/user/mailtxt
ADDR="mail@domain.com"

  echo -e `date` > $TEXT
  echo -e "1\n\n\nq" | menu >> $TEXT
  mutt -s "$SUBJ" -i $TEXT -- $ADDR < /dev/null
```

I want it to pipe "echo -e 1\n\n\nq" to the script Menu and in turn get the output in a file. The output from Menu will just be text.

Comment: You are trying to run this script from cron, or you're trying to run the commands from cron? Because I seem to recall cron mucks with the stdin/out/err streams

Comment: Perhaps "not same user" means that your cron script runs as a user that does not have permission to write to `/disk2/home/user/mailtxt`. Or the cron job does not have the `menu` command/script in its PATH.

Comment: Not having permissions was a problem, I fixed that. I will look it in to cron stdin/out/err and if cron has the menu script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (as suggested) was that the cronjob did not have the script 'menu' in it's path. Changing "menu" in the script to the absolute path fixed it.

```
echo -e "1\n\n\nq" | /folder/folder/menu >> $TEXT
```

EDIT: Do not forget to set the correct permissions on the textfile if the cronjob is run by another user.